# Pass Argument into GraphQL query

Tags: reactjs, graphql

My React component needs to fetch one particular item,

the query looks like this:

```
const ITEMS_QUERY = gql  `query GetEntry($id: ID!) {
  getEntry(id: $id) {
    id
    date
    items {
      items {
        id
        entryID
        name
        amount
        hazardRating
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
    createdAt
    updatedAt
  }
}
`;
```

The query takes in an ID as an argument in order to fetch one Item, how do I pass in the id variable from the following React component:

```
const Items = (id) => {

    const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(ITEMS_QUERY(id));

    console.log(id)

    if (loading) return "Loading...";
    if (error) return <pre>{error.message}</pre>
  
    return (
        <div className="Items">
         dddd
        </div>
      );

}
```

I have attempted to pass in the id variable like so: useQuery(ITEMS_QUERY(id)) but this is obviously not correct and I don't expect it to be so...

How would you pass the id variable from the component into the ITEMS_QUERY ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [useQuery API here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries#usequery-api), you're missing the options attribute:

```
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(ITEMS_QUERY,{ variables: id });
```

Comment: You also need to adjust your component. Props are passed as an object, so instead of:

const Items = (id) => {

try:

const Items = ({ id }) => {

Comment: Works, thanks Will. Also I didn't need to change the id as Cody suggested - it worked straight away without changing